# alpine package py-pip missing

Tags: docker, dockerfile, alpine-linux

Im trying to install python pip in my alpine using Docker compose file but get the following error.

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  py-pip (missing):
    required by: world[py-pip]
ERROR: Service 'web' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c apk add py-pip' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Have a look at https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.3/main/x86/py-pip

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Do `update` first:

```
apk add --update py-pip
```

Or:

```
apk update
apk add py-pip
```

Answer (score 23):

For python3 on alpine edge:

`apk add py3-setuptools`

Comment: That's also "missing"

Answer (score 23):

You have to use appropriate pip version depending on Alpine branch:

- Alpine v3.12 or newer, use `apk add --update py3-pip`
- Alpine v3.5 - v3.11, use `apk add --update py2-pip`
- Alpine v3.3 - v3.4, use `apk add --update py-pip`

Answer (score 8):

For me `--no-cache` option worked.

> apk add --no-cache py-pip

Answer (score 8):

I've found the following:

```
$ apk add --update py3-pip
```

Answer (score 5):

Following command in the console should work with any linux distro:

`python -m ensurepip --upgrade`

Tested succesfully with Alpine v3.17 the VM edition. More details [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/).

Answer (score 1):

AlpineWSL 3.14.0 | Last commands is a solution, info from ircs://irc.oftc.net/alpine-linux

```
apk update
apk upgrade
apk add python2
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

Example

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
...
Successfully installed certifi-2021.10.8 chardet-4.0.0 idna-2.10 requests-2.26.0 urllib3-1.26.7
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.3.4 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Comment: This worked for me for Python 3 (specifically using `python3` instead of `python2`) on Alpine 3.17.0-rc4

Comment: its 2023 where Python2 is officially dead and unsupported by the python software foundation. Users should not downgrade to prior versions.

Answer (score 1):

For future folks running into this and similar issues with missing packages, you might just need to edit /etc/apk/repositories and uncomment the 'community' repo.

py-pip and py3-pip at least are there.

Answer (score -1):

You need to modify your repository:

Modify the file /etc/apk/repositories

Add the repository community

g.e.:

```
/media/mmcblk0p1/apks
http://alpine.42.fr/v3.14/main
http://alpine.42.fr/v3.14/community
```

For me, the server used is http://alpine.42.fr, but you can use another server

Don't forget to commit your change if you want to have this configuration permanently

```
lbu commit -d
```

Answer (score -2):

This worked for me:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/pip/2.7/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py && python get-pip.py
```