# Docker alpine apk cannot find git-lfs package

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I'm trying to install `git-lfs` in a Docker alpine image, but I'm getting an error indicating:

> ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
>    git-lfs (missing):
>      required by: world[git-lfs]

It seems that there has been many issues related to apk not finding packages (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48869833/alpine-unsatisfiable-constraints-missing-packages) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44633903/alpine-package-py-pip-missing)), and in many cases these have been solved by using the `--no-cache` option with `apk add`. But I am not being that lucky and cannot understand the origin of this error, specially considering that git-lfs is up to date in [alpine repo](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=git-lfs&branch=edge).

The following small Dockerfile should reproduce the error:

```
FROM alpine:3.4

RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache \
        build-base \
        git \
        git-lfs
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that git-lfs is available only from alpine:3.7.

To fix the issue you should either rebuild it on your own or use an alpine version >=3.7.

Btw, you don't need to execute `apk update`.

Comment: This fixes the problem indeed, Thank you. Just for knowing in the future, is it possible to know in advance if one package requires a given version of alpine or not? To me is not obvious from the package website.

Comment: to be honest, I did it in a unpleasant way... This is the address: https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.7/community/x86/git-lfs from here I tried to go back with versions to see if it was available...  Not the nicest way :P

Comment: That what I call brute force! But no doubt it works :D